# WCF windows credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

my client on server A calls a service on B which calls a service on C.
In order to get the call working from B->C I have to do this:

```
channel.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = 
   new System.Net.NetworkCredential("WndowsUserName", "WindowsPassWord");  
IService1 service = channel.CreateChannel();
```

etc...

the user name and password are the windows credentials used from A->B
Of course I do not want to hardcode this so how can I do this without hardcoding?

I tried, with no luck:

```
WindowsIdentity callerWindowsIdentity = 
    ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;  
using (callerWindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

property. It represents the authentication credentials for the current security context in which the application is running. Details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx).

Comment: DefaultNetworkCredentials has all empty properties when i run it in the client app and from inside my service!?! And that link is in chinese :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a "double hop" authentication problem. 
In short, NTLM doesn't alllow more than one "hop" with it's credentials (token). So user authenticates on server 1 with it's token, and in turn, server 1 tries to send the token to server 2. This won't work, unless Kerberos deleguation is allowed between server 1 and 2.

More details here : http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx
And here : http://blogs.msdn.com/nunos/archive/2004/03/12/88468.aspx

Comment: Does the same apply when hoasting in a console app? I'm guessng yes are that is what i'm doing! So if using Windows Authentication is the work around what i am doing i.e. use a different users account information to go past the first hop?

Comment: Yes it applies. NTLM token can only "do" one hop. If you want to allow more hops, you have to use Kerberos delegation to "allow" one server to transmit the token it has to another server.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the class

```
System.Net.CredentialCache
```

could be helpfull ...
It has the DefaultCredentials and DefaultNetworkCredentials properties that you can use.
Offcourse, you will have to make sure that your application runs under the credentials that you want (that is , the credentials of the current user).
This can be done by calling

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy (PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
```

At the start of your program.

Then, when you initialize the WCF service, you can use the `DefaultNetworkCredentials` provided by the `CredentialCache`.

```
channel.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
IService1 service = channel.CreateChannel();
```